# Red Hat Linux 5.11 ftp username and password spec

Tags: linux, passwords, ftp, restrictions, username

Apols if dumb question in wrong place.

On Red Hat Linux 5.11
re ftp command

i.e. ftp "client", connecting to a (remote) ftp server/location.

(fwiw package manager only has ftp package ver 0.17-38.el5)

I was wondering about it's limitations, re number of characters and illegal characters, specificaly wrt username and password (the assumption being the ftp server(s) being connected to have no length or character restrictions).

i.e.:

Is there a maximum length for the username?

Is there a maximum length for the password?

Are any characters disallowed for the username?

Are any characters disallowed for the password?

Comment: Are you taking about the FTP client or the FTP server? The restrictions on the client are usually those of the server it connects to. For the server the ids are usually those of the system so the system restrictions apply.

Comment: thnx, re-edited post, its ftp command issued in shell script to fetch files from a remote ftp server. So I would understand this to be client.